# How to perform chain tasks in RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to perform tasks in RxJava one by one.

**For Example:-

**1. **Fetch User Ids from Server**

2. Fetch Users from server by thier Ids.****

I have tried this method

```
public Observable<List> getUids(){
       return Observable.create(emitter -> {
           List<String> uids = new ArrayList<>();
           //fetchData from server
            emitter.onNext(uids);

       });
}

public Observable<User> getUser(String uid){
       return Observable.create(emitter -> {
           User user = new User();
           //fetchData user from server
            emitter.onNext(user);
       });
}

//Executing this code like 

   getUids().flatMapIterable(ids -> ids)
               .flatMap(this::getUser)
               .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onNext(User user) {
                   print("next "+user.getName());
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onError(Throwable e) {
                   print("error "+e.getMessage());
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onComplete() {
                   print("complete");
                 }
             });
```

There are some problems in it
 1.this is not calling Subscriber's `onComplete()` method when all users are fetched.
2.if there is an error in `getUser` method, app is crashing. with `io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException` exception

Can you please tell me where I am mistaking?

Comment: Can you use `disposable`?

Comment: i am new to  RxJava.I will do any solution if it solves my problem

Comment: use the `flatMap` operator for unordered results or `concatMap` for ordered i.e `task1.getIds().flatMapIterable(ids -> ids).flatMap(id -> task2.getUser(id)).subscribe(user -> { ... })`

Comment: I am doing it already

Answer (score 0):

1. Call `emitter.onComplete()` in your `getUids()` and `getUser(...)` Observables and then append `.toList()` after `.flatMap(this::getUser)`.

   > Returns a Single that emits a single item, a list composed of all the items emitted by the finite source ObservableSource.
2. `UndeliverableException` is a wrapper for the exception that is happening in your `.flatMap(this::getUser)`. I can not help you more with the information that you provided, what is it that you want to happen when an exception is thrown?

Comment: for example if i push ```emitter.error(new Throwable("error"));``` in ``getUser``` Method it throws ```UndeliverableException```

Comment: Read this article concerning the `UndeliverableException`: “The RxJava2 Default Error Handler” by Bryan Herbst https://link.medium.com/FKNzrtj4kW

Comment: and subscriber is not invoking after adding  .toList()

Comment: Your `getUids()` Observable has to complete after emitting the uid list.

Comment: ```Single<List<Student>> listSingle = getUids().flatMapIterable(ids -> ids)
                .flatMap(this::getUser)
                .toList();
        listSingle.subscribe((students, throwable) -> {
            if(throwable != null){
                print("error "+throwable.getMessage());
            }else{
                print("done");
            }
        });
```


not working